Как изменить размер окна программы если он залочен?
Недавно перешел с ПК на ноутбук, к которому подключил второй монитор.
Для программы ZBrush мне нужен графический планшет, у меня есть Parblo A610. Но проблема в том что какую бы версию драйвера/софта для этой модели планшета я не установил, интерфейс в окне программы не отображается полностью. Из-за этого я даже не могу выбрать в проге нужный мне монитор для работы. Рамка окна залочена и расширить ее мышкой нельзя.


Проверил разные настройки разрешения экрана.
Настраивал параметры запуска программы в Свойствах.
Обновил драйверы встроенной видеокарты.
Переустанавливал разные версии программы множество раз.
Проверил базовые хоткеи винды по работе с окнами.
Пытался задать размер окна через AutoHotkey и Sizer.

Ноль реакции на все мои действия. При этом на ПК проблем с этим окном не было и оно сразу отображалось корректно.
Есть ли у вас какие-либо предположения по решению этой проблемы? Возможно ли вообще решить ее программным способом (если конечно не рассматривать покупку другого планшета)?

попробуй размер шрифта подкрутить

@eri не помогает

https://www.ubisoft.com/ru-ru/help/connectivity-and-performance/article/changing-your-monitors-dpi-for-windows-10-and-windows-11/000065536

а винда какая?.
